# Android и JSON, ошибка разбора

Tags: php, android

Имеется код:

```
String line = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
bufferedReader.close();
result = sb.toString();
Log.e("Resul-----------",result);
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
int success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
```

Json приходит примерно вот такой: 
`{"message":"Пользователь добавлен.","succes":1}`

Ошибка:

```
E/Resul-----------: {"succes":1,"message":"\u041f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c \u0434\u043e\u0431\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d."}
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"message":"Пользователь добавлен.","succes":1} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
                  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
                  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
                  at com.example.danilshik.myapplication.RegisterActivite$createUser.doInBackground(RegisterActivite.java:157)
                  at com.example.danilshik.myapplication.RegisterActivite$createUser.doInBackground(RegisterActivite.java:111)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Думаю из-за кодировки не может обработать json. Как исправить?

PHP:

```
$response = array();
$response["succes"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Пользователь добавлен.";
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: У вас не массив приходит, а объект. Используйте Gson для json-а и retrofit2 для запросов

Comment: @РусланЯгупов можете привести пример использования

Comment: смотрите [здесь](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit), [и здесь можно](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-adding-customizing-the-gson-converter)

Comment: @danilshik, Ваш `json` не массив, а объект `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);` - создавайте сразу объект и разбирайте дальше.

Comment: @woesss так?JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                int success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
                String message = jsonObject.getString("message");

Comment: Да, так. Или опять не получается?

Comment: @woesss Нет, выдает E/Resul-----------: {"succes":0,"message":"\u041f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c \u0441 \u0442\u0430\u043a\u0438\u043c \u043d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440\u043e\u043c \u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d\u0430 \u0443\u0436\u0435 \u0441\u0443\u0449\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0443\u0435\u0442."}
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for success

Comment: ошибку нашел, спасибо